# MYSQL : PHP ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

Tags: mysql

When i am trying to login in mysql shell using

```
mysql -u root -p
```

i am getting the

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

Please help me out what is wrong with mysql

I am able to login using `mysql --host=127.0.0.1 frontend`

**Update**
/etc/hosts

```
  127.0.0.1       localhost
    127.0.1.1       shweta-desktop
    127.0.0.1       webfaction
    # The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
    ::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
    fe00::0 ip6-localnet
    ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
    ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
    ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Comment: please add your /etc/hosts file to the question

Comment: *netstat -ln | grep mysql* will tell you where the socket path is

Answer (score 1):

I found that it was because the mysql database wasn't running use this command to start it

```
service mysqld start
```

Comment: I think you meant "service mysql start"

Comment: @PSeUdocode No, the mysql daemon service in RedHat flavors is known as `mysqld`. It's a bit incorrect to say that it's not running that command tho. You typically set [chkconfig](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/s2-services-chkconfig.html) to make a service start on boot. The above command is for manual start/stop

Answer (score 0):

The answer of sandhaya is not wrong, regarding your comment there.
See this answer on Serverfault and the comments:
https://serverfault.com/questions/295285/mysql-cannot-connect-via-localhost-only-127-0-0-1

To summarize it: If you connect to mysql with the special vhost-name "localhost" (which is the default), mysql tries to connect to the socket specified in your /etc/my.conf.
This seems to be an incorrect one. 
What´s wrong with your your host-alias i cannot say, your /etc/hosts seems correct.
So connecting with 127.0.0.1 is actually a solution, the other is to find the correct soccet and place it in your /etc/my.conf.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue. I found that I had a .netrc in /root that had info in it.

I deleted it and problem gone.

Able to log into mysql using `mysql -uroot -p` without issue now.